# AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer not found

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I am creating a sample application using http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ tutorial, i have added required jars but still getting "AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer cannot be resolved to a type" in WebSocketConfig.java file.
Which jar i need to use this as currently i am using spring-webmvc-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar,spring-websocket-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar and spring-messaging-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of Maven/Gradle and [Spring IO Platform](http://platform.spring.io/platform/) is to take care of this for you.
Those guides are updated frequently, and it looks like you're not importing the right version of Spring anyway...

Maven and Gradle are requirements for those guides - could you try building that guide with Maven or Gradle?

Answer (score -1):

I hit this issue and I'd like to offer the solution I found. Please read the gradle buildfile in this post [ConcretePage](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-websocket-sockjs-stomp-tomcat-example#gradle) at the heading "Gradle for Spring 4 WebSocket Application" and consider whether the maven repos and the dependencies shown there can assist you as they did me. I added the repositories shown there, and all the dependencies and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following dependency to you **pom.xml**

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```